# How to write the HQL query

Tags: mysql, hql

I have a database table which is used to save the education experiences. It has 4 attribute.

1. userId (a foreign key relate to User table)
2. beginDay (the time of enrollment)
3. endDay (the time of graduation)
4. school (the name of school)

Now I have a userId and I want to select the last education experience according the userId.

How to write the hql query?

I have written

```
select * from education where userId = 100 and beginDay = max(beginDay)
```

but the query is wrong. Console output invalid use of group function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this query for that:

```
SELECT * FROM education WHERE userId = 100 ORDER BY beginDay DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: can it select the last education experience  of userId = 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM education e where e.UserId = 100 and e.beginDay = max(e.beginDay)
```

Should work. I don't know exactly how your DB looks

If I recall correctly, you need to get the full class structure if it is a foreign key value. Its been a while...

```
FROM education e where e.User.UserId = 100 and e.School.beginDay = max(e.beginDay)
```

Comment: I think foreign is not important.

Comment: SELECT * FROM education WHERE userId = 100 ORDER BY beginDay DESC LIMIT 1. This query can select the last education experience of userId=100 ? I don't have compute to test now

Comment: Do you think it will work? I feel it's a good way to solve my problem

Comment: I used to use similar HQL syntax when we used HQL. I haven't touched it in a while. I think it will work provided your XML mapping is defined logically. I don't have the class hierarchy so its difficult for me to guess. If I am correct, then I believe it will work

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: No problem. Good luck

Answer (score -2):

```
String hql = "select * from education where userId = 100 and beginDay = max(beginDay)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Comment: This is the full HQL query Syntax.

Comment: Please explain your answer.